# Найти такую пару чисел, в которой оба числа чётные, а сумма наибольшая. Вывести сумму

Tags: python

На вход подаётся число N, а затем N натуральных чисел в строчку. Записать их в массив. Найти такую пару чисел, в которой оба числа чётные, а сумма наибольшая. Вывести сумму.
Была идея записывать чётные значения в новый массив и там уже суммировать элементы, но вышел провал.

```
N = int(input())
number = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
even = [int(i) for i in number if i % 2 == 0]
for j in range(N-1):
for i in range(N-1):
    print(even[i]+even[i+1])
```

Comment: так even или uneven? и проверку на четность можно сделать сразу в первом list  comprehension

Comment: @strawdog исправил

Comment: Так в провал у вас в чем? вам можно пользоваться модулями, например itertools? если да. то создаете список со всеми возможными комбинациями пар четных чисел без повторений и находите ту, чья сумма больше.

Comment: @strawdog зачем же составлять кучу комбинаций, когда достаточно взять максимальное число и второе максимальное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заведите переменные max1, max2

Пройдите по списку. Если число x четное, то проверяете, не больше ли оно, чем max2. Если да, то проверяете ещё, не больше ли оно, чем max1. Если да, то

```
max1, max2 = x, max1
```

иначе

```
max2 = x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
N = int(input())
number = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
even = [int(i) for i in number if i % 2 == 0]
even.sort()
print(even)
print(even[-1] + even[-2])
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).